# Proving Bayes formula relative to equivalent martingale measures.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Here is the statement that I wish to prove (Bayes formula):

> Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalent probability measures on $(\Omega, ~ \mathcal{F})$, let density: $Z = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$，and $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ to be a $\sigma-$field, then:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\big[ X ~ \big| ~ \mathcal{G} \big] = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ZX ~ | ~ \mathcal{G}]}{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z ~ | ~ \mathcal{G}]}
> $$

---

I derive a proof as follows, but I think there's obviously something wrong with it (or it may not even make any sense).

> For $\forall G \in \mathcal{G}$，since $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$，and hence $G \in \mathcal{F}$, then for $\forall G \in \mathcal{G}$:
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\big[ X ~ \big| ~ \mathcal{G} \big] & = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[ X \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ]}{\mathbb{Q}(G)} \\
> & = \frac{\int ~ X \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ~ d\mathbb{Q}}{\int ~ \mathbb{I}_{G} ~ d\mathbb{Q}} \\
> & =  \frac{\int ~ ZX \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ~ d\mathbb{P}}{\int ~ Z \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ~ d\mathbb{P}} \qquad \text{(Since $d\mathbb{Q} = Z \cdot d\mathbb{P}$)} \\
> & = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ ZX \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ]}{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G}]} \\
> & = \frac{\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[ ZX \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G} ]}{\mathbb{P}(G)}}{\frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z \cdot \mathbb{I}_{G}]}{\mathbb{P}(G)}} \\
> & = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\big[ ZX ~ \big| ~ \mathcal{G} \big]}{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\big[ Z ~ \big| ~ \mathcal{G} \big]}
> \end{align*}
> $$

Would you please identify the mistake that I made in the above?

Comment: The first equality is wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\big[ X ~ \big| ~ \mathcal{G} \big] $ is a function on $\Omega$, so I think if $w \in G$ then the first equality would hold. Could you please provide more hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with the definition of conditional expectations by the Radon-Nikodym integral equations:
A random variable $Y$ is the conditional expected value of $X$ given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$ with respect to a probability measure $\mathbb P$ if for all $G\in\mathcal G$ we have $$\int_GXd\mathbb P=\int_GYd\mathbb P$$

Now in this setting we have for every $G\in\mathcal G$: $$\int_G Xd\mathbb Q = \int_G \mathbb E^\mathbb Q[X|\mathcal G]d\mathbb Q$$ as well as $$\int_G Xd\mathbb P=\int_G\mathbb E^\mathbb P[X|\mathcal G]d\mathbb P$$ Then by $Z=d\mathbb Q/d\mathbb P$ we get
$$ \int_GZ\cdot Xd\mathbb P=\int_GXd\mathbb Q= \int_G \mathbb E^\mathbb Q[X|\mathcal G]d\mathbb Q = \int_G Z\cdot \mathbb E^\mathbb Q[X|\mathcal G]d\mathbb P$$ It follows that $\mathbb E^\mathbb P\big[Z\cdot\mathbb E^\mathbb Q[X|\mathcal G]\big|\mathcal G\big]=\mathbb E^\mathbb P[X|\mathcal G]$

Now you need to know a bit of basic theory of conditional expectations to rewrite the left-hand side and obtain the desired result.